# I need grails to add an alias onto the system generated constraints

Tags: oracle, grails

I am using grails and oracle. When the default constraints are created by grails for unique, relation etc constraints they are done as system generated constraints, with id's like SYS_C0060279. The problem I am having is that between the dev/test/prod systems these id's are differnt because all are created in the same db just different schemas. So what I would like to do is have some way to possibly alias all the auto generated constraints in grails so they are not system created and will be consistent with refreshes across the environments?

I am trying to use liquibase to manage all the differences but the constraints are being painful because every env has a different constraint name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and don't just suggest mysql or postgres ;).

Cheers David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails Object Relational Mapping uses Hibernate 3. I think it's not implemented in Hibernate.
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3499

[specifying constraint name in hibernate mapping file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119981/specifying-constraint-name-in-hibernate-mapping-file)